# Generating Postman preview from PHP

Tags: php, postman, suitecrm

So i've been trying to use the suiteCRM REST API but i keep getting stuck every time i tried to authenticate to the API and everything i tried seems to fail, so now i been trying to reverse engineer a code snippet that i found [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Jfs.png) in PHP. the code works when i runt it, but now i'm trying to use it in postman but a i get "invalid login"...i would really appreciate it if you can see what i'm missing

**The code**

```
<?php

$url = "https://demo.suiteondemand.com/service/v4_1/rest.php";
$username = "will";
$password = "will";

function call($method, $parameters, $url)
{
    ob_start();
    $curl_request = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

    $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($parameters);

    $post = array(
         "method" => $method,
         "input_type" => "JSON",
         "response_type" => "JSON",
         "rest_data" => $jsonEncodedData
    );

    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $result = curl_exec($curl_request);
    curl_close($curl_request);

    $result = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result, 2);
    $response = json_decode($result[1]);
    ob_end_flush();

    return $response;
}

//login ---------------------------------------- 
$login_parameters = array(
     "user_auth" => array(
          "user_name" => $username,
          "password" => md5($password),
          "version" => "1"
     ),
     "application_name" => "RestTest",
     "name_value_list" => array(),
);

echo "++++++++++";
echo md5($password);
$login_result = call("login", $login_parameters, $url);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($login_result); //nothing
echo "</pre>";


//get session id
$session_id = $login_result->id;

echo "<pre>";
echo "****************";
print_r($session_id); //nothing
echo "</pre>";
```

**What i've tried**

[image]

any help on this is greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Send your data as JSON:

[image: Postman Example]

If this doesn't work, show your request and response header please.